# How can show text array according options checked?

Tags: javascript, ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-3, ruby-on-rails-4

I'm trying to show texts according checkbox selected.

I have 3 states so when I check one or two checkboxes will show me options selected without javascript.

For example:

```
if I check1 will show me the text active.
if I check2 will show me the text inactive.
if I check3 will show me the text inactive and active.
if I check1 and check 2 will show me the text "active","inactive".
if I check1 and check 2 will show me the text "active","removed".
if I check1 and check 2 will show me the text "removed","inactive".
```

Just keep the text according the checkbox selected.

Here is the controller:

```
@search_state = params[:search_state]
@people = Person.all
```

Here is the view:

```
<%= form_tag(people_path,:method => "get") do %>
 #### BEGIN CHECKBOX #####
 <% if @search_state.blank? %> 
   Check1 <%= check_box_tag "search_state[]", "0" %>
   Check2 <%= check_box_tag "search_state[]", "1" %>
   Check3 <%= check_box_tag "search_state[]", "2" %>
 <% else %>
   Check1 <%= check_box_tag "search_state[]", "0", @search_state.collect(&:to_i).include?(0) %>
   Check2 <%= check_box_tag "search_state[]", "1", @search_state.collect(&:to_i).include?(1) %>
   Check3 <%= check_box_tag "search_state[]", "2", @search_state.collect(&:to_i).include?(2) %>
 <% end %>
  #### END CHECKBOX ####

 ### WANT TO SHOW A TEXT ACCORDING CHECKBOXES SELECTED ###
   <% if @search_state.to_s=="0"%>
     Active
   <% elsif @search_state.to_s=="1"%>
     Inactive
   <% elsif @search_state.to_s=="2" %>
     Removed
   <% elsif @search_state.to_s==["0","1"] %>
     Active,Inactive
   <% elsif @search_state.to_s==["0","2"] %>
     Active,Removed
   <% elsif @search_state.to_s==["1","2"] %>
     Inactive,Removed
   <% elsif @search_state.to_s==["0","1","2"] %>
     Active,Inactive,Removed
   <% end %>
   ### END WANTTO SHOW A TEXT ACCORDING CHECKBOXES SELECTED ### 
 <% end %>
```

Here are files and demo:

```
http://runnable.com/VMkReiHVr0FbfQKN/checkbox-project-test-for-ruby-on-rails
http://runnable.com/VMkRe1xPNqFWSMtd/output
```

My code is too long and I think is not the correct way of doing this.

For example in this case I have 3 states, if I have more states will be too long and confusing.

Somebody Can help me to make the checkbox whithout several lines of code using ruby on rails,please?

I know that using Javascript is the solution, but Is the only way to resolve and How could be the solution please?

I will really appreciate all kind of help.

Comment: Can you add an explanation of what you are trying to achieve exactly? I don't think you are doing "it" the right way but I am not sure what "it" is... Can you write the expected behavior of the functionnality ?

Comment: Sorry MrYoshiji , I mean about without writing several lines of code according checkboxes, if I have more checkboxes the code will be too long, and i think is not the correct way need to make it more dynamic

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'm having a hard time following what you intend it to do from your examples.  But I think you mean that button 1 is "Active" , button 2 is "Inactive", and button 3 is "Removed".  Further, I think you intend that no options are mutually exclusive...in particular, you can check "Active" and "Inactive" at the same time.  You also imply that there may be many more checkboxes in the future that will behave similarly.

If all that is correct, then I agree, your current approach will not scale well at all.

Instead of trying to select a complete message based on complex criteria, I would refactor it to build up the message from its components.  Something along these lines should get you there:

```
  flags = []
  flags << 'Active' if @search_state.collect(&:to_i).include?(0)
  flags << 'Inactive' if @search_state.collect(&:to_i).include?(1)
  flags << 'Removed' if @search_state.collect(&:to_i).include?(2)

  puts flags.join(', ')
```

FWIW, if you don't have a reason to give all the checkboxes the same name and different values, I would give each one a different name.  This will make a lot of your code much simpler.  Something along these lines:

```
   Check1 <%= check_box_tag "search_active", "1", @search_active == 1) %> Active
   Check2 <%= check_box_tag "search_inactive", "1", @search_inactive == 1) %> Inactive
   Check3 <%= check_box_tag "search_removed", "1", @search_removed == 1) %> Removed
```

If you really need them in an array, you can join them together later on easy enough.

Comment: Oh god you you are the master, I noticed you don't have a long score to demostrate you know. Thanks David it worked for me.

Comment: Thanks for your time and experiencie +1.